# ImageCaptureService using up all my CPU resources

Tags: macos, cpu

I am not really sure why ImageCaptureService is doing on my computer.

From what I understand, it is a preinstalled application that comes part of Carbon.framework.

However, I am not doing anything intensive on my computer, and my fans are going full blast on my max spec mid-2015 Macbook Pro.

When I check Activity Monitor, it shows that ImageCaptureService is using nearly 100% of my CPU, which is preposterous.

Can someone tell me what exactly this program is doing, and if I can disable it?

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of my Activity Monitor]

If it helps, here is the output in the Open Files and Ports information

```
/
/System/Library/Services/ImageCaptureService.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageCaptureService
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ShowStatusTemplate.pdf
/usr/share/icu/icudt55l.dat
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText-Regular.otf
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSDisplay-Regular.otf
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Base.lproj/IKDeviceBrowserHeaderView.nib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Base.lproj/IKDeviceBrowserDataView.nib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IKScanMagicPocket@2x.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IKScanMagicPocket.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Gradient@2x.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Gradient.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HideStatusTemplate.pdf
/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
/System/Library/Extensions/AMDMTLBronzeDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMDMTLBronzeDriver
/System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver
/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
/System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver
/System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver
/System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ATIRadeonX4000SCLib.dylib
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantLightAppearance.car
/private/var/folders/4v/jn67z0956rzc0w693063f24c0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-134501.csstore
/usr/lib/dyld
/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
/dev/null
/dev/null
/dev/null
count=2, state=0x12
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantLightAppearance.car
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the issue was that I had an external monitor plugged in. When I unplugged my monitor, there was a box that appeared that said "Choose your camera". When I closed the box, the CPU usage dropped entirely.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Tim's reply](https://superuser.com/a/1543126/444074) (which has the working solution: disconnect external monitor and close "Select a camera or a scanner" windows), I've managed to find the root cause.

The "Select a camera or a scanner" window appears after right-clicking in document editor like MS Word, Outlook, etc. and choosing `Import Image` or `Services / Import Image`.

Apparently, when using multiple monitors, the "Select a camera or a scanner" window gets hidden out of view and eats up CPU.